# how to check whether email is entered in proper format or not in html,php

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
username:<input type="text" name="username">
<br>
password:<input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
```

I want to alert if @ is not included in email field i.e email should be in proper format otherwise it should throw alert.

Comment: email field you say...That will be extremely difficult.

Comment: use  email input `<input type="email" name="email">` [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_email)

Comment: Uhm, `<input type="email" required />`

Comment: You can start off by making the `type` of your input field `email`.

Comment: it's all in conditional statements and checking if something is equal to something and "contains". Surely, you can research this and "try something".

Comment: Don't forget about Regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: Nice of you to post questions, get answers/solutions then just run off. You need to hold up to your title as "Computer Engineering".

Answer (score 0):

In view use email input `<input type="email" name="email">` in html5.

In php validation `filter_var`

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     //Valid email!
}
```

See more about filter_var: http://www.php.net/filter_var

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has come up with many different input types and you can perform the validation at the user interface level. You can do that by

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required >
```

In php:

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
    if (preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z.-_-@0-9]/", $email)) {
                die("Email format is wrong.");
            }

            if (!(strrpos($email,'@')< strripos($email,'.'))) {
                die("Email format is wrong. Email should be like name@example.com");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate_email($eml){

  $eml_components = explode('@', $eml);

  if(!isset($eml_components[1]) || !strpos($eml_components[1],'.')){
    echo "Invalid email format.";
  }else{
    echo "Valid email format.";
  }
}
```